# outlook 2013 incoming mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've build a VBA-Project that checks the inbox on special emails,
extracts the attachement and save the attachement on the network.
this all happens when the user clicks on a button.

My problem now is that I want to automate this.
Therefore I've tried to rewrite the VBA project but
when an email arrives I always get the error message
'Unzulässiger oder nicht ausreichend defnierter Verweis'

(tr. Improper or no sufficient defined reference)

I can't figure out what to do and therefore I'm trying
to get an answer here.

Attached you'll find the code which is placed in 'ThisOutlookSession'

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim objNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim X As Integer

Set objNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Items = objNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim objNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim strPath, strAuditPath, strSavPath, strFolderName As String
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim objTrash As Outlook.Folder
Dim intAnlagen, intTotal, i As Integer

Set objNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error GoTo check_error

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Msg = Item

    If Msg.SenderEmailAddress = "notify@someone.com" Then 
        If Left(Msg.Subject, 8) = "QHST-Log" Then 

        strSavPath = "D:\Users\AS400_QHST_Logs\"
        strPath = "T:\DOKUMENTE\AS400\QHST-Logs\"
        strAuditPath = "D:\Dropbox\QHST-Log\"

        strFolderName = Right(Msg.Subject, 4)
            If Dir(strPath & strFolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then 'Prüfen ob Subfolder der Form JJJJ angelegt ist.
                MkDir strPath & strFolderName
                MkDir strAuditPath & strFolderName
                MkDir strSavPath & strFolderName
            End If
            strPath = strPath & strFolderName & "\"
            strAuditPath = strAuditPath & strFolderName & "\"
            strSavPath = strSavPath & strFolderName & "\"
            strFolderName = Mid(.Subject, 14, 2)

            If Dir(strPath & strFolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then 
                MkDir strPath & strFolderName
                MkDir strAuditPath & strFolderName
                MkDir strSavPath & strFolderName
            End If
            strPath = strPath & strFolderName & "\"
            strAuditPath = strAuditPath & strFolderName & "\"
            strSavPath = strSavPath & strFolderName & "\"

            intAnlagen = Msg.Attachments.Count
            intTotal = intTotal + intAnlagen
            'Debug.Print objNewMail & ": "; intanlagen
            If intAnlagen > 0 Then
                For i = 1 To intAnlagen
                    Set oAttachment = Msg.Attachments.Item(i)
                    oAttachment.SaveAsFile strPath & oAttachment.FileName
                    oAttachment.SaveAsFile strAuditPath & oAttachment.FileName
                Next i
            End If
            Msg.UnRead = False
            Msg.Delete
        End If
    End If
End If

check_error:
Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
If Err.Number = 75 Then 
   Err.Clear
   GoTo Back1:
Else
   Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Description
End If

Err.Clear
Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ich spreche kein Deutsch

Comment: Try change all your German to English as English is more common thus more people can help.  Also in case you have not done it where is the error occuring?

Comment: @Alex - the error occurs when a new mail arrives at the statement: Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Set objNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Edit: Reference the Application Object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865800%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Syntax

expression .GetNamespace(Type)

expression A variable that represents an Application object.